# asadmin command doesn't work in ubuntu

Tags: java, terminal, glassfish, enterprise, asadmin

I'm using Java EE with Glassfish.

I can't run asadmin command as well. I did the following, but output from terminal is:

> ```
> No command 'asadmin' found, did you mean: Command 'amadmin' from   package 'amanda-server' (universe) Command 'acsadmin' from package'ion' (universe) asadmin: command not found
> ```

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr. I should be in bin directory of glassfish, so I'm in /opt/glassfish4/bin.
But always nothing happend, just error message above.

Comment: My solution is here: when I add "sh" before whole command, it works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Ubuntu and Linux in generál, you run commands from current directory like this: `./asadmin`, ie. you must prepend `./` to make it explicit that you run a command I current directory. This is traditionally for some security reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Try following command `export PATH=/installationDirectory/glassfishName/bin:$PATH`

In my case it was `export PATH=/opt/glassfish4/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

The `asadmin` command needs to be read from glassfish bin directory when executing commands, hence you need to export the following in your environment variables.
On mac,

```
export PATH=/Users/macpro15/Downloads/glassfish5/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you are creating the domain inside the default domain. You should make your own domain in the domains folder, and the run the following command in your terminal:

```
sh asadmin start-domain DOMAIN_NAME
```